# Python execution order using subprocess.call

Tags: python, subprocess

I have the following code in file abc.py:

```
import subprocess
def evaluate():
    for i in range(5):
        print("Printing", i)
        subprocess.call(['ls', '-lrt'])
        print("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
evaluate()
```

Now when I call using python abc.py > out.dat, the output file contains the result of 'ls -lrt' five times which is followed by printing statements in the code.
Why is it happening so and what should I do if I need to get output as:

```
printing 0

(results of ls -lrt here)

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

printing 1

.
.
.
```

and so on..?

Thank you..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to flush your stream before you call a subprocess:

```
import subprocess, sys
def evaluate():
    for i in range(5):
        print("Printing", i)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        subprocess.call(['ls', '-lrt'])
        print("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
evaluate()
```

Flushing takes automatically place line-by-line as long as you write to a terminal (without redirection).  Then you do not notice the problem because the `print()` flushes at the newline.

As soon as you redirect your output to a file the `print()` statement notices this and flushes automatically only when a certain buffer is full (and at termination time).

The subprocess (`ls`) does the same but uses its own buffer.  And it terminates first, so its output is in the file first.

Comment: This will still printout all "Printing #" before. He expects that it will print 1, then the results, then print 2... etc. The indentation is wrong.

Comment: It was wrong in the OP, then was wrongly fixed by another user, I relied on that version.  Understood now, fixed both OP and my post.  I hope now everything's aligned.

Comment: That worked perfectly, the indentation in my post was wrong, I have corrected it, but nevertheless, I got the idea. Thanks a lot Alfe